# Title: Angular - Images and icons disappear from the page after change detection is triggered

Tags: javascript, angular, openid-connect, ng-bootstrap, cache-control

Problem Statement:
I have an Angular(v12) webpage with several images and icons. These images are either svg, png or icons imported by the [ngb](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/home) library. When the page loads initially, all the icons and images render properly with no issues. I also have [OIDC](https://openid.net/) configured in my project. So whenever the [silentRenewal](https://authts.github.io/oidc-client-ts/classes/UserManager.html#startSilentRenew),[Angular auth](https://angular-auth-oidc-client.com/docs/documentation/silent-renew) method of OIDC is called, it internally triggers change detection. After the change detection, many of the images and icons disappear from the page.

[Image before:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EIw8T.png)
[Image After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yh1IQ.png)

When I inspect the icons, their URLs are correct and they open perfectly in a new tab, it is just they don't render on the page. It is not just a single component that is being affected by this. Icons of many components like header, side-bar dashboard etc. disappear after the OIDC method is called.

Also, I am only able to reproduce this in chrome, safari and edge browsers, firefox browser renders the icons properly.

After observing the network tab, I found that the images are being fetched every time the silentrenewal method of OIDC is being called. As there is no change in the URL of the image for each subsequent fetch, it returns 304 (re-rendering with no modification). We also have some DNS server setup for this project to host on different host rather than localhost.

Because of this, it seems like an issue of image cache busting. When I toggle the 'Disable Cache' option in the chrome developer tools, the icons are rendering fine every time. One of the workaround which worked for me was that I tried giving current date-time as query params to every image, example: `assets/logo.png?1669960657`. This works for the images that we are referring from the `assets` folder as we can append the query parameter for those image urls, but I have no way of applying this for the images and icons in other npm libraries or images used in css files with background-image property url. This approach also seems like a workaround and not a proper fix.

I'm looking for a better solution for this issue.

Other things that I have tried to resolve it:
1.) Triggering change detection manually by applying changeDetectionStretegy onPush at component level and using changeDetectorRef at afterViewInit cycle.
2.) Changing urls of images and icons to use absolute path instead of relative path.

> 

```
Here is my package.json file for reference:

{
  "name": "xyz",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "prebuild": "npm --no-git-tag-version version patch",
    "dev": "ng serve --host testgenius.zeuslearning.mumbai --aot",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/localize": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "~12.2.0",
    "@circlon/angular-tree-component": "^11.0.4",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^10.0.0",
    "@ngrx/effects": "^13.0.2",
    "@ngrx/store": "^13.0.2",
    "@ngrx/store-devtools": "^13.0.2",
    "@tinymce/tinymce-angular": "^4.2.4",
    "ag-grid-angular": "^27.0.0",
    "ag-grid-community": "^27.0.1",
    "angular-multi-step-form": "^1.2.8",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.0",
    "bs-stepper": "^1.7.0",
    "chart.js": "^2.9.3",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "html2canvas": "^1.4.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "moment": "^2.29.3",
    "ng-multiselect-dropdown": "^0.3.8",
    "ng-template": "^1.0.0",
    "ng2-charts": "^2.2.3",
    "ngx-image-cropper": "^6.1.0",
    "ngx-toastr": "^14.2.2",
    "oidc-client": "^1.11.5",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "tinymce": "^5.10.1",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "xlsx": "^0.18.5",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~12.2.11",
    "@angular-eslint/builder": "12.7.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "12.7.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "12.7.0",
    "@angular-eslint/schematics": "12.7.0",
    "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "12.7.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~12.2.11",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~12.2.0",
    "@types/crypto-js": "^4.1.1",
    "@types/file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.8.0",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.181",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "4.28.2",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "4.28.2",
    "eslint": "^7.26.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.8.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~1.7.0",
    "typescript": "~4.3.5"
  }
}
```